# how to randomly assign all observations to two groups evenly

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, my data has 2000 observations.
I want to create a new variable called group, which essentially is a random assignment of 1 or 2 but has 1000 counts of 1 and 1000 counts of 2.

Is there a command from dplyr that can do this?

Comment: To randomly pick 1000 items out of 2000 use this: `sample(1:2000, 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same number of each element but a random order, just do:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(rand = sample(rep(c(1,2), times = 1000)))
```

The `rep` ensures that the counts of 1 and 2 are the same, and `sample` randomizes the order.

Comment: it works when I have 2000 observations. but when I have 1999 observations, what times should I use? I tried 999 or 1000 or 999.5, but neither works

Comment: You have to do 1000 of 1, and 999 of the other.

Comment: Something like `df %>%
  mutate(rand = sample(rep(c(1,2), times = c(1000, 999))))`.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Consider leaving a green check mark if this answers your questions so others know it is correct.